# count of a value from different column by column wise count

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns having values 0 and 1 like give below

Column A = 0,1,0
Column B = 0,1,1
Column C = 1,1,1

I need to count occurrence of "1" from each column. (eg. A = 1, B = 2, C = 3). Kindly guide me to get the count based on column count.

Comment: Are these `0,1,0` in separate rows or concatenated on the same row?

Comment: 0,1,0 are 3 different row values of A column

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a string trick.  Try this:

```
SELECT LENGTH("0,1,1") - LENGTH(REPLACE("0,1,1", "1", ""));
```

It returns 2.

So:

```
SELECT LENGTH(A) - LENGTH(REPLACE(A, "1", "")) AS A_count,
       LENGTH(B) - LENGTH(REPLACE(B, "1", "")) AS B_count,
       LENGTH(C) - LENGTH(REPLACE(C, "1", "")) AS C_count
    FROM ...
```

If you had a bit string, see `BIT_COUNT()`.  If you have a character string with 0s and 1s, `BIT_COUNT(convert(my_str, 2, 10));`

Consider writing a Stored Function to encapsulate the tricky code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 END) AS aCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN 1 END) AS bCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cCount
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I miss something, but why not just sum it up?

```
SELECT SUM(A), SUM(B), SUM(C)
FROM t
```